# Segger Embedded Studio linking error STM32F7

Tags: embedded, linker-errors, stm32, elf, stm32f7

at the moment I'm trying to import a SW4STM32 project for the STM32F746G-Discovery board into the Segger Embedded Studio.

The initially project works fine but with the Segger Embedded Studio I've got some problems.

After some small problems (missing user paths,..) the project finally "builds", let's say it runs through all sourcefiles without any error.

Now I have an error and I don't know why. 
I get a linking error while working with the internal toolchain. "not a 32-bit ELF File"

Has anybody got this error? I'm currently searching for any hint.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Here are the Files
[Makefile,...](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15EpV7euxWVDl6IyIzhPjT2QmYwsS4EJ2)

Comment: please show the linker and makefile, because this will have the answer and we can't answer without seeing

Comment: Providing a Google drive link is not really appropriate.  Presumably somewhere in the IDE there is a plain-test log of the build - you should provide that rather then a screenshot of the IDE filtered/structured messaging - in most cases these hide information that is useful to diagnostics.  _"not a 32-bit ELF File"_ is likely an error message from the _from elf_ utility.  The question is why export_segger.elf is not a valid ELF file; for that we need to see how it was generated.